# PSFeed - how to set it "empty"

Tags: cocoa, publish-subscribe

I'm using a PSFeed bound to an arraycontroller in my nib. the user can enter a simple RSS feed into a text field, by pressing enter, PSFeed gets the new feed URL. if the user does not enter any feed (empty textfield) and pressed enter I'm worked the following workaroung to force PSFeed refresh to return an empty feed entries list. This way my arraycontroller gets updated with an empty list.

Any idea to do it better?

here the snippet which assigns an dummy "http://error.ch" to feedUrl, urlFeed is the textfield.

```
- (IBAction)changeFeedUrl:(id)sender {
feedURL= SmartURLFromString([urlFeed stringValue],
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"http",@"https",@"file",@"feed",nil]);
if (feedURL)  // Update with new scheme
    [urlFeed setStringValue:[feedURL absoluteString]];
else {
    feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlErrorFeed];
    [urlFeed setStringValue:@""];
}

NSLog(@"changeFeedUrl %@",feedURL );
[newsFeed initWithURL:feedURL];
feedError = nil;
[self refreshFeed:nil];
}
```